# Canonical transformation in field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, phase-space

I am working with a condensed matter system in terms of charge and spin bosonic fields $\phi_c$ and $\phi_s$, respectively. I am trying to reach a diagonal Hamiltonian by diagonalizing the following matrix:
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{V_c}{2K_c} & \frac{\Delta}{4} & 0 & 0 \\\\
\frac{\Delta}{4} & \frac{V_s}{2K_s} & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & \frac{V_c K_c}{2} & \frac{\Delta}{4} \\\\
0 & 0 & \frac{\Delta}{4} & \frac{V_s K_s}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I could perform the diagonalization of this, finding that the new dynamical variables for the system would be of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{-}N_1 & N_1 & 0 & 0 \\\\
u_{+}N_2 & N_2 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & v_{-}N_3 & N_3 \\\\
0 & 0 & v_{+}N_4 & N_4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\phi_c \\\\
\phi_s \\\\
\Pi_c \\\\
\Pi_s
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the $N_i$'s are normalization constants for the eigenvectors of $M$.

My problem is that I expected the new fields, say $\phi_{a/b}$ and $\Pi_{a/b}$, to satisify $$[\phi_{a/b}(x), \Pi_{a/b}(y)]=i\hbar \delta(x-y),$$ which ended not being the case, for example:

$$[\phi_a(x), \Pi_a(y)]=N_1 N_3(u_{-}v_{-}+1)i\hbar\delta(x-y)$$

I started with canonical varibles $\phi_{c/s}$ and $\Pi_{c/s}$ and after diagonalization I lost the canonical commutation relation. Where I messed up when diagonalizing $M$? Shouldn't I expect to get canonical fields after it? Should I move forward and study the system in terms of these fields anyway? How could I fix this issue of the commutator?

Comment: Are the transformations to the new variables unitary? If not, you should be able to convert them to unitary transformations be rescaling the eigenvalues.

Comment: They are. $M$ is symmetric so the matrix with the eigenvalues is orthogonal. By choosing the $N_i$'s as real, for example, it ends up being unitary.

Comment: What you want is a Bogoliubov transformation of the variables. Indeed, there are requirements for there to be a change of basis that respects the commutation relations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Yes, I know the Bogoliubov transformation but I'm having troubles implementing it here because my vector of operators doesn't contain operators with the same algebra (in the case of the Bogoliubov transf. it would be either annihilation or creation) but I'm dealing with $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=0=[\Pi(x),\Pi(y)]$ and $[\phi(x),\Pi(y)]=i\delta(x-y)$.